# Laravel route [login] not defined inside a file

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, routes

I am building a modular application in laravel. I created a `User` module and here is the routes:

```
<?php
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web', 'namespace' => 'Modules\User\Http\Controllers'], function()
{
    Route::get('/', 'UserController@index');
    Route::get('login', 'LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');
    Route::post('login', 'LoginController@login');
    Route::post('logout', 'LoginController@logout')->name('logout');
});
Route::group(['middleware' => 'admin', 'prefix' => 'user', 'namespace' => 'Modules\User\Http\Controllers'], function()
{
    Route::get('register', 'RegisterController@showRegistrationForm')->name('register');
    Route::post('register', 'RegisterController@register');
});
```

The `route('login')` statement returns the url to `login` page and it works well. Inside the `config.php` I need  to access this function as follows

```
<?php

return [
    'name' => 'User',
    'menu' => [
        'weight' => 1,
        'item'  => [
            'Login' => [route('login'), 'guest'],
            'Register' => [route('register'), 'guest'],
        ]
    ]
];
```

Inside this file the error `Route [login] not defined.` is reported. Why is this undefined in there?

I also tried adding the following line

```
namespace Modules\User\Http\Controllers;
```

But it still not working

thanks

Comment: Have you ran `php artisan route:clear`

Comment: @thisiskelvin yes. still not working. But I can see this url in any other controller

Comment: what is `config.php`? a file in the `config` folder? if that is the case these files would be read before a request is available (for the url generator) and before routes are defined

Comment: Try to store only route name in config file and convert it to url whenever you need like this `route(config('config.menu.item.Login.routename))`